# App generated photo/video not appearing in Google Photos app

Tags: android, media

I have an application that generates an output video, I'm saving it in the DCIM folder, however, when trying to look for the video in the Google Photos app, it doesn't appear.

It's as if the output video wasn't generated at all (using File Manager app, the videos are actually displaying)

Is there a metadata or something I need to attach so the videos I generated would appear?

Comment: Use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method to arrange for the `MediaStore` to index the video.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, that worked for me.